# Assign new created product to client clientName.txt

Tags: java

I have  class :`Product (name,price)` , class:`Client (name,age)`.
I do have a main where I create  clientList and productList so from here I can save the client and procuct to the clientname.txt

I do ask the client to input the new product also  and then that product will be saved into the `ProductList.txt` .
I try to write inside the clientname.txt also the input from the client that suppose to be also in the list of products .
My maine looks like this :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Product product = new Product("Headset", 59);
        Product product1 = new Product("Charger", 16);

        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(product, product1));

        Client client1 = new Client("Victor", 28);
        Client client2 = new Client("Mihai", 20);
        Client client3 = new Client("Alex", 25);

        List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(client1, client2, client3));


        System.out.println("Welcome to the menu!");
        HashMap<Integer, String> menu = new HashMap<>();
        menu.put(1, "adding clients to the file (each file for each client)"); // create file  for client/s
        menu.put(2, "adding products to a file");// one file to save all products // ask client to create new product  name + price
        menu.put(3, "assigning a product to a customer (add product to file of client)");// adding the product from the file  productList to the file of the client
        menu.put(4, "reporting (print all)"); // print client by name
        menu.put(5, "Exit"); // system exit

        menu.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + "- " + value));
        int user_choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a number from 1 to 5:");
        user_choice = in.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1:
                createFileForEachClient(clientList);
                writeClientToFile(clientList);
                break;
            case 2:
                createFileProducts();
                writeNewCreatedProductToTheFile(productList);
                break;
            case 3:
                writeProductToAssignedClient(clientList, productList);

                break;
            case 4:
                readFileByName(".txt");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for `case 2:` where I ask the client to "create the `ProductList.txt`"
and create new product that automaticly write to the created file `ProductList.txt`

```
//product list file
public static void createFileProducts() {
    try {
        File file = new File("ProductList.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// save all products to the file (create new product and save it  to the file)
public static void writeNewCreatedProductToTheFile(List<Product> productList) throws IOException {
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the name:");
String prodName = in1.nextLine();
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter price:");
Integer priceProduct = in2.nextInt();
Product prod = new Product(prodName, priceProduct);
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("ProductList.txt", true);
fileWriter.write(prod + "\n");
fileWriter.close();
for (Product product : productList) {
    FileWriter fileWriter1 = new FileWriter("ProductList.txt", true);
    fileWriter1.write(product + "\n");
    fileWriter1.close();
   }
}
```

So what I try to do is  : When client input `case 3:`  that suppose to add to all the clients all the products(from product list and also the ones that client create/input), what I get is only the products that are already created in `prodcutlist` but not  the one that client input(please see my method below  `writeProductToAssignedClient(clientList, productList);`)
Here is the method that I write to write all the products inside the clientname.txt file/s:

```
 public static void writeProductToAssignedClient(List<Client> clientList, List<Product> productLis) {
        try {
            for (Client client : clientList) {
                for (Product prod : productLis) {
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(client.getName() + ".txt", true);
                    fileWriter.write(prod + "\n");
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can someone let me know what I do wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that  this is working for me , I did look around and found that I can  just "copy" all what I have in my `ProductList.txt` to each `clientname.txt` file .
Here is the code I used :

```
public static void writeProductToAssignedClient(List<Client> clientList) {
    try {
        for (Client client : clientList) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "ProductList.txt"));
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(client.getName() + ".txt", true);
            BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            String str;
            while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                outputStream.write(str + "\n");
            }
            outputStream.close();
        }

    } catch (
            IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```